# Two Relativelayouts display vertically

Tags: java, android, layout, user-interface

Here's the XML code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Welcome"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Welcome"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It's not really the scene (The UI design is not that code, but I'm presenting it for simplification).
What I except from this code is that the TextViews will be displayed one by another relatively (in a vertical way). Like:

```
                     Welcome
                     Welcome
```

But instead the output is the following:

```
                     Welcome
```

Like, they're nested together, stacked on each other. 
I made the width layouts as fill parent, so why the other layout doesn't go down? it overrides the first relativelayout.

**I must have 2 layouts, so please don't suggest me to create only one layout.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the relation of your layouts.

Try the modification I've made below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/top_rel>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Welcome"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@id/top_rel>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Welcome"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've given the top layout the `android:id="@+id/top_rel"` to make it's identification easier.

Also I've told it to be laid out at the top of the view by using `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`.

The lower `RelativeLayout` then is being laid out below the top one by using `android:layout_below="@id/top_rel"`.

Comment: Can't accept your answer since it's too early, I'll be accepting it in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, give some id of the  Relative layout corresponding the first text view. Then using the id, add the layout_below property for the second relative layout. So that it will display below of the first text view..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">


 <RelativeLayout
        android:id = "@+id/first_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Welcome"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/first_layout">
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Welcome"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```